# Cleanly handling void as generic return type of labmda in C++

Tags: c++, generics, lambda

I am trying to write a function like this:

```
template <typename T>
void testActionBehavesIdentically(Foo& fooA, Foo& fooB, std::function<T(Foo&)> action)
  if (std::is_same<T, void>::value)
  {
    // perform action even if T is void
    action(fooA);
    action(fooB);
  }
  else
  {
    // if T is not void, test also return values
    T resultA = action(fooA);
    T resultB = action(fooB);
    CHECK_EQUAL(resultA, resultB);
  }
  // tests that the state of both foos is the same
  CHECK_EQUAL(fooA, fooB);
}
```

where `T` is sometimes `void`. The compilation (on VS2019) fails with
`error C2182: 'resultA': illegal use of type 'void'`. Is there a clean way around it? (Hopefully one that will compile in most standard compilers)? Thank you.

Comment: You need `if constexpr` to conditionally compile the branches, instead of `if`.

Comment: Use *specialization* instead?

Comment: Not sure if VS2019 supports C++17. If it does, use `if constexpr`. If it does not, use overloads or full specializations.

Comment: @SergeyA Not only does VS2019 supports C++17, it now supports fully C++20 as well! But beware that the default standard used is C++14.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now what's happening is that the compiler still will compile both `if` branches (since it doesn't actually know which will be called until runtime). This results in a failure since one of the branches doesn't compile correctly. There are a couple fixes (from the comments):

If your compiler supports it this would be one option:

```
  if constexpr (std::is_same<T, void>::value) {
    // perform action even if T is void
    action(fooA);
    action(fooB);
  } else {
    ...
  }
```

this will only actually *compile* one branch depending on the type of T.

If your compiler doesn't support it, here's another option:

```
template <typename T>
void testActionBehavesIdentically(Foo& fooA, Foo& fooB, std::function<T(Foo&)> action) {
    // check assuming T != void
}

// overload which will be called if T was void
void testActionBehavesIdentically(Foo& fooA, Foo& fooB, std::function<void(Foo&)> action) {
    // check assuming T == void
}
```

The compiler will match the overload when T is void instead of dispatching to the generic version of the function. Here you could even say "if T is an `int` do something different" which is kind of neat (but can get messy).

Comment: FWIW, instead of specializing, you should overload.  For one, it's less typing and easier to read.  Secondly function template specializations are second class citizens in C++ and have confusing rules.  Here is a great video on the subject and details some of the reasons why function template specializations for standard library functions has been removed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIDEjY5ywqU

Comment: Thanks, I switched it over to an overload instead - good suggestion!